# UIView animation doesn't work if app goes to background

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I have a little questions game where if the user takes too long to answer, it times out and automatically triggers a custom segue to a certain screen.

```
    let firstClassView = self.sourceViewController.view
    let secondClassView = self.destinationViewController.view
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    firstClassView.clipsToBounds = true
    secondClassView.clipsToBounds = true
    let secondClassFrame = CGRect(x: screenWidth, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
    secondClassView.frame = secondClassFrame
    guard let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow else {
        return
    }
    window.insertSubview(secondClassView, aboveSubview: firstClassView)
    if let questionVC = self.destinationViewController as? QuestionResultViewController {
        questionVC.prepareResultView()
    }
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstClassView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstClassView.frame, -screenWidth, 0)
        secondClassView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondClassView.frame, -screenWidth, 0)
    }) {_ -> Void in
        self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

This code and the segue works fine, EXCEPT if the user sends the app to the background (and opens it again) before the segue. In this case, the UIView.animate block is reached, but it's contents seem to never be called, so no animation plays! (I got a print command in there, and it was not being triggered)

If my description was confusing:

Case 1:

- User reaches question screen
- Question's timer times out
- Segue triggers
- Animation block is reached and plays perfectly

Case 2:

- User reaches question screen
- Sends app to background
- Opens app again
- Question's timer times out
- Segue triggers
- Animation block is reached, but nothing happens -> ???

Why is this happening? I tried using layoutIfNeeded and it's variations, but nothing worked. The animation block's contents are never called.
From my tests using breakpoints, the app stops completely before it reaches the UIView line (and ends up crashing after ~10 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it had nothing to do with the UIView block. I had a custom UILabel class, and it's layoutSubviews method was entering an undetectable infinite loop after the app went to background.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your code is not a correct custom presentation animation, so you can't be surprised if things break down. You can't just go messing with frames and do a presentViewController like that. You need to write a proper custom presentation animation. What you are doing was _always_ wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p302addingPresentationController/PresentationController/ViewController2.swift

Comment: In my case, the example is an UIStoryboardSegue subclass, do you have any example with it or should I just never use it?

Comment: You can absolutely do this in a UIStoryboardSegue subclass. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p325customSegue/CustomSegue/ViewController.swift

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not fixed the issue. I believe I have screwed up some constraints. But thanks for the files!